# How to remove all other duplicates in range Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I need to remove duplicates in a bit of a complicated way. For the selected row, I need to remove all other duplicates and for other rows I need to keep the earliest entry.

What I'm thinking (Selected row: | Steve | 10pm |:

1. Remove duplicate Steve entries other than this one (4pm & 1pm)
2. Sort by time
3. Get unique values

---

```
Table before:
| Steve | 10pm |      
| Mike  |  8pm |   
| Steve |  4pm |   
| Joe   |  6pm |   
| Mike  |  3pm |
| Steve |  1pm |   

Ex1: 
Selected: | Steve | 4pm |
| Steve |  4pm |        
| Joe   |  6pm |    
| Mike  |  3pm |  

Ex2
Selected: | Steve | 10pm |
| Steve | 10pm |
| Joe   |  6pm |
| Mike  |  3pm |

Ex3:
Selected: | Steve | 1pm |
| Joe   |  6pm |
| Mike  |  3pm |
| Steve |  1pm |
```

---

Edit: 12/19/2016 12:02am

I found the solution to my specific problem. The answer below turned out to be correct for removing the duplicates. I was able to successfully figure out a position. I realized just now, however, that this isn't a proper solution to the larger problem I have...

```
=MATCH(B2,unique(INDEX(SORT(sort({query(B2:C, "select B, min(C) where B <> '" &B2  & "' and B <> '' group by B label min(C) ''", 0); B2:C2}, 2, false),2,1 ),0,1)),0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, your data is in column A:B and the selected (somehow?) row has been copied to C1:D1. (Whatever is your selection method, you should be able to make the selected row appear somewhere). Then a possible strategy is:

1. Use `query` to select all non-Steves,  picking the earliest time for each.
2. Add the selected row to the results
3. Sort the whole thing as you want.

Here is how I did it; the queried range begins with 2nd row to avoid (likely) headers.

```
=sort({query(A2:B, "select A, min(B) where A <> '" & C1 & "' and A <> '' group by A label min(B) ''", 0); C1:D1}, 2, false)
```

Same with linebreaks:

```
=sort({
   query(A2:B, 
     "select A, min(B) 
        where A <> '" & C1 & "' and A <> '' 
        group by A 
        label min(B) ''
     ", 0); 
   C1:D1}, 
 2, false)
```

So the query picks the names different from C1, and groups by name choosing the earliest time. It does not use any header labels, to avoid them getting mixed in with the sort. The row C1:D1 is appended using array notation `{row1; row2}`, and finally the array is sorted by the second column in decreasing order.

Comment: This is reallllyyy close. The problem is; I need to apply this formula for each row... The end result ideally, will be a number.

Comment: I'm realizing now that maybe asking the generic question would have been better X_x

Comment: Just realized how to make it work. Will get back to you in a few.